# What's wrong with my bootchart?

Tags: 10.04, boot

Currently my Ubuntu takes quite a bit to boot ~1min. Windows is about the same, even faster I think.

I installed bootchart and ran it but not sure what to make of the results. Can someone take a quick look and suggest what could speed up my laptop's boot time?

EDIT: I Also have latest dmesg file here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/624611/

Image also updated after deleting all *.pack files

[image]

Comment: Is it possible you could make this available to download so that I can better diagnose it.

Comment: @scouser73 Sorry, do you mean the image? You can just right click > save image.

Comment: Can you try to find the right `/var/log/dmesg` file for that bootchart (add it to your question using http://paste.ubuntu.com)? One thing: ureadahead isn't running. Delete all *.pack files in `var/lib/ureadahead`, reboot, wait a minute, reboot making a bootchart and check it. But looking at the ntfs-3g thingy, that doesn't seem to be the only problem here.

Comment: What filesystem is your root fs?  ureadahead only works with ext[234], so if you are using something else, that would explain it.

Comment: @htorque Wow, following your suggestion just shaved off 20s of boot time and looks like ureadahead ran! Are you suggesting that there's an issue with ntfs-3g? I need to be able to access an NTFS partition (that's where I store all files so it's "shared" with Windows, that's why I have it there.)

Comment: I'm not sure there's something wrong, I just don't see that much CPU load (blue) for those NTFS related processes here.