# Extremely slow boot

Tags: boot

I am having difficulty finding a fix for my slow boot. Along with Ubuntu taking long time to boot it also will sometimes not load and after restart and on boot. I am running Ubuntu 12.04  LTS. 64-bit. Dell XPS M1730. I am extremely new to Linux so there may be an easy fix for this. I may end up having to reinstall Ubuntu. I was trying to avoid that.

`[    3.374844] input: Broadcom Corp as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-2/3-2.3/3-2.3:1.0/input/input9`

`[    3.374936] generic-usb 0003:0A5C:4503.0005: input,hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Broadcom Corp] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-2.3/input0`

`[    7.977885] EXT4-fs (sda1): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem`

`[    7.977888] EXT4-fs (sda1): write access will be enabled during recovery`

`[    9.336852] EXT4-fs (sda1): recovery complete`

`[    9.337253] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)`

`[   19.007787] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready`

`[   19.093301] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro`

`[   19.108582] udevd[498]: starting version 175`

I'm getting anywhere from 50 to 200 seconds of boot time. On average im getting more errors like:`ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready` I have gotten up to 4 of these errors in one boot. I am assuming once I fix one error all of them should clear up.

I have searched forums, but all I see is temporary fixes and hardware issues. I have tried shutting off my wireless, disconnecting all USB drives, and disconnecting my network cable all have been without success or change in boot time. I have seen alot of fourms with people who are getting the same error and they have a long shutdown time. My shutdown time is where it should be takes about 10 seconds (max) to shutdown.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Install bootchart (it is in the repos; more info here: http://www.bootchart.org/ ) and when you have a slow boot check the timestamps on the image bootchart made. Also have a look here at htorque's comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/48253/whats-wrong-with-my-bootchart

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use ethernet you can add it to blacklist. I reduced my boot time from 140 seconds to 70 seconds(still too much, searching for other reasons).

Here's an [instruction](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149514/disable-ethernet-permanently-to-speed-up-boot-time) how you can do it.

Comment: Please elaborate on the question and not just provide the link. Thanks