# Which loaded kernel modules are unused and should I disable them?

Tags: kernel

I want to know the kernel modules which are not being used now. So, that I can disable them from loading at boot time?

Is there any method to see which kernel modules *(of course, loaded)* are not in use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Most modules are automatically loaded only because the corresponding hardware was detected

`lsmod` shows you the currently loaded modules, as (excerpt):

```
Module                  Size  Used by
...
psmouse                87692  0 
bluetooth             180104  7 bnep
parport                46562  3 lp,parport_pc,ppdev
serio_raw              13211  0 
snd_ens1371            25747  4 
gameport               19693  1 snd_ens1371
snd_ac97_codec        134826  1 snd_ens1371
joydev                 17693  0 
...
```

However, just because ***Used* is 0** for a particular module does not mean it is not in use!

Note that the kernel autoloads modules based on the hardware detected, except for the modules listed in `/etc/modules`, which are "force"-loaded.

#### Removal/blacklisting will disable hardware; no real need on modern systems with more than 512MB of RAM

So if you remove or blacklist any of these modules **beware: that piece of hardware may no longer work.** e.g. if I remove/blacklist `parport`, my parallel port won't work, which is OK if I never use it. The same goes for `bluetooth` ,etc.

The kernel modules take up relatively little memory on a modern PC, so the only time I'd recommend this kind of manual "optimization" is on embedded systems, etc. with little RAM.

---

### For Disabling the modules

From a later comment by OP, It seems that, he wanted to know the loaded *unused* modules names to disable them from auto loading in the boot time. It can be achieved by blacklisting them.

- A good help can be found [from this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/149590/61218)
- Also see this question [How to blacklist kernel modules?](https://askubuntu.com/q/110341/61218)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Can i know more precisely How much RAM can I save by disabling them *(if I disable them)*?

Comment: It's the  number of bytes shown in the Size column of `lsmod`

Comment: Thanks, I actually wanted to disable them to decrease boot time.

Comment: @AnwarShah, then disable the ones for hardware you don't use/need (blacklist) -- this won't work for built-in modules though. And an upvote and accept (if you feel the answer deserves it) would be appreciated :)