# How can I edit a .conf file owned by root?

Tags: boot, root, ethernet

I'm trying to create an exception file to disable my ethernet as I think it's responsible for my 350s+ boot times, please see section of dmasg below :-

[    3.750961] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  364.079424] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready

I'm following this answer [Disable Ethernet permanently to speed up boot time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149514/disable-ethernet-permanently-to-speed-up-boot-time) and I've created the file but I can't save the edited version, the permissions tab tells me it's owned by root.

Any help is most appreciated. I'm a proper linux newbie, trying to get it to work on this laptop is my first foray into Ubuntu. I read messing with the root 'account' is not something for people who don't know what they're doing (i.e. me!). Please be gentle :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to open the terminal (ALT+CTRL+T) then enter:

`gksu gedit /path/to/file.conf`

Enter your password, then edit the file and save.

Comment: In reply to edit: "_Never use sudo with GUI software_" I never knew about that as it always worked fine for me, could you do me a favor and explain why?

Comment: Actually, it can cause extraneous files to be left. However, you can use `nano` if you know how.

Comment: [What is the difference between gksudo nautilus and sudo nautilus](http://askubuntu.com/questions/11760/what-is-the-difference-between-gksudo-nautilus-and-sudo-nautilus)

Answer (score 2):

A more general solution that also works in 18.04 and later in which gksu has been removed from the repositories, virtual consoles (tty) and on headless Ubuntu Server operating systems is to use Ubuntu's built-in default text editor for editing files from the terminal.

```
sudoedit /path/to/file.conf
```

This is logically equivalent to writing the same command the long way:

```
sudo nano /path/to/file.conf
```

The instructions for using nano text editor are always displayed at the bottom of the page. Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file to its current location. Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.