# Moodle installation on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04

Could not open the file “/opt/lampp/apps/moodle/htdocs/config.php”.

I need to edit this file line 30.

Comment: What error message does it give you, and what editor are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I edit a .conf file owned by root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184878/how-can-i-edit-a-conf-file-owned-by-root)

Comment: Make sure you use the answer provided by @karel  rather than the accepted answer to the linked question:  The command in the linked question has been removed from Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If you are following the installation instructions from [moodle.com](https://docs.moodle.org/36/en/Step-by-step_Installation_Guide_for_Ubuntu) you may have missed a small, but essemtial point.  Their command line

> cd /var/www/html/moodle sudo vim config.php

realloy should be broken into correct separate lines, as:

```
cd /var/www/html/moodle
sudo vim config.php
```

The `sudo` part of the second command will prompt you for your password, and grant you root privileges for the editing of the "config.php" file.  This could have been done in a single line command with

`cd /var/www/html/moodle && sudo vim config.php`