# Turn off ethernet without turning off WiFi

Tags: wireless, networking, power-management

I'm new to Ubuntu but somewhat familiar with PCI. I noticed that when I disable networking (by unchecking the 'Enable Networking') the eth controller moves to D3 state (sudo lspci -vv), but that also means I have no WiFi and it too moves to D3.

Is it possible to 'decouple' the two? I never use the eth, and would like to have it turned off / in D3 in order to save power, but would still like to have WiFi.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable Ethernet permanently to speed up boot time](http://askubuntu.com/questions/149514/disable-ethernet-permanently-to-speed-up-boot-time)

Comment: The proposed duplicate question was asked for a different purpose (improve boot time) than yours (save battery time) but it answers your question.

Comment: @papukaija I don't think that question is relevant here since when I `rmmod` the driver the device is still on (D0).

Comment: @papukaija I've tried the method described in your link, and still in D0. So this is definitely not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

try `sudo ifdown eth0` which disables the interface

Comment: I get `ifdown: interface eth0 not configured` since eth0 is not up. Dstate remains D0 anyway.